# Should I choose my former supervisor as a referee, even though my personal issues unfairly put him under a lot of pressure?

Tags: supervision, reference-request

This question is potentially UK-specific.

A couple of weeks ago I received a conditional offer of appointment to become a temporary Coronavirus Response worker in a Welsh NHS hospital, and now I am being asked for further references, covering January 2019-March 2020 (I've already provided three for June-December 2018).

I would ask my former supervisor (Fred), who is a senior academic and senior academic administrator. I hope the following will illustrate why I am uncomfortable with this:
Early in my degree I failed to attend resit exams due to an attitude problem. (My mother had just been admitted to a psychiatric hospital, and also I was angry at the university for having put my friend, who had just committed suicide, under too much stress.) My studies were terminated, but after an intervention by my housemate, Fred and his colleague invited me back in for an appointment. They re-admitted me (onto a Leave of Absence) after I explained about my mother and blamed the university for my friend’s suicide.

I ended up on some of Fred's courses (including field courses). He is a lovely man and always wants the best for people, but I let him down a lot. For example, I failed to attend to give a graded presentation at his compulsory seminar, a mini-session for those like me who couldn't make it, and an appointment arranged personally with Fred to give my presentation to him by myself. But he still gave me a good grade for the presentation after I sent a video of myself giving the presentation in the empty lecture hall. Anybody else would have refused to accept it.

More seriously, I was probably the most burdensome student who Fred has ever supervised during my final year project. (Fred just so happened to be the administrator responsible for finding a replacement supervisor after my first one fell ill. When this proved impractical, he took me under his wing himself.) After being granted several lengthy extensions due to another close friend committing suicide (this time within our department, so Fred was at the funeral too), each achieved milestone made a mockery of the planned timescales. In the end Student Services, Fred and I had a collapse in confidence in the usefulness of deadlines to structure my work.

Student Services advocated to Fred very energetically for me, partly because of my dyslexia/ADHD and partly because I was becoming increasingly depressed/suicidal as every new deadline approached. (Having two friends who’d committed suicide I didn't think it would be such a big deal anymore, and in any case I felt there wasn’t much point continuing if I couldn't achieve my goal of supporting my mother financially due to lack of a degree). They were probably scared as well, since 4 months after my second friend’s suicide I casually admitted to having been  in possession for the past 3 months of the same substance she’d used, in case I ever needed it. (Student Services sent somebody around to confiscate it.) Fred probably read between the lines that I was suicidal. In any case Fred was meant to supervise me for 3 months after my first supervisor fell ill, but this gradually extended to 10 months. This included periods up to 2 weeks long where I avoided reading emails from Fred (or anybody else outwith Student Services), because I couldn't see how communication or excuses would help. I feel that he was unfairly under immense pressure to grant me accommodations, sometimes even pre-emptively in consultation with Student Services.

I have now finished my studies and am graduating with a 2:2.

According to an NHS template for for how to contact references (see https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.wsh.nhs.uk/CMS-Documents/Trust-policies/151-200/PP18190References.pdf&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwixooPA397pAhWREMAKHRnLB_AQFjAAegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw3h_4i6ZHSNfxhbzW0KkHuu)
"we have to... request previous employers to advise us of time taken off on the grounds of sickness over the last two years. Therefore, I should be grateful if you could give details of any sickness absence, including any long absences, together with the reasons given... it will be important for us to have such details before we can make an unconditional offer of employment." 
I am not sure what Fred could answer in this regard which would reflect well on me.

Should I still ask Fred if he would referee for me? I feel I've already put him through enough difficulties, and I wonder whether it would be better to go for character references (from friends or my former driving instructor, who is quite elequent) plus my study support tutor.

Comment: A reference letter is not a big ask, and writing such letters is a standard part of his job.  You have probably already spent twice as much time writing this question as it would take him to write the letter.  I'd say you should stop worrying and just ask him.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge I presume this will be a phone reference when dealing with NHS HR, not a reference letter. I would be concerned that he might give a negative impression in the phone reference, and I am unsure whether this would be better than phone references from my study support tutor+ a phone character reference from one of my friends.

Comment: References are part of his job, whether by phone or letter or whatever.  When you contact him to ask about the reference, you can ask him what he'd expect to say, and how he'd address your past issues if at all.  I don't know much about the UK, but it seems to me unlikely that references from a driving instructor or personal friends would be of any help whatever in a job application.

Comment: After some quick research I doubt the NHS would accept a letter he passes to me first: "important to distinguish between references and testimonials. The latter are usually documents given to the candidate by a referee (often worded 'to whom it may 
concern'). The Trust does not accept these in place of references." - https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.wsh.nhs.uk/CMS-Documents/Trust-policies/151-200/PP18190References.pdf&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwixooPA397pAhWREMAKHRnLB_AQFjAAegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw3h_4i6ZHSNfxhbzW0KkHuu

Comment: @Nate Eldredge I also have reason to believe they would ask about my sickness history, and I am not sure whether whatever Fred could say would reflect well on me. From an NHS template at the same link: "we have to... request 
previous employers to advise us of time taken off on the grounds of sickness over the last 
two years. Therefore, I should be grateful if you could give details of any sickness absence, 
including any long absences, together with the reasons given... it will be important for us to have such details before we can make an 
unconditional offer of employment."

Comment: Okay.  You may need to get advice on that from someone who is more familiar with the NHS employment process, which is outside the scope of this site.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge Are character references of no help whatsoever?

Comment: That is just my guess, but again, I am not the right person to be asking.

Comment: I think academic references for the NHS are within the scope of this site, because I'm sure that refs for the NHS would be a matter of interest especially to British academics. The NHS employs 1.5 million people and I wouldn't be surprised if it the largest graduate employer in the UK by number of graduates employed.

Comment: All right.  I will leave this question for those who are better qualified to answer it.

Comment: The trick with job applications is to present problems/foibles in a positive light. Despite health/personal difficulties, **you got the degree in the end** -- well done! You just need to reframe the narrative as "a triumph against the odds". Overcoming such adversity could even be treated as "strength of character", and might be just the sort of experience that would be valued for work that requires sensitivity and compassion (as patient-facing NHS work does, surely...).

As for the referee, if you are that worried about it, how about **asking** Fred before making a final decision? Good luck